# Insertion Sort using compareto() in a arraylist of strings

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
{
  int j = i;    
  int orderNum = list.get(j).toLowerCase().compareTo(list.get(j - 1).toLowerCase());
  while(j > 0 && orderNum < 0)
  {
    String temp = list.get(j);
    list.set(j, list.get(j - 1));
    list.set(j - 1, temp);
    j--;
  }
}
```

So I want to sort an ArrayList of Strings with an insertion sort in alphabetical order and the ArrayList is for example ["boy", "Eat", "apple", "code", "Tea"] but it turns out to be ["code", "apple", "boy", "Eat", "Tea"] so I don't know what's going on even though I have been reviewing my code.

Thanks

Comment: The sort works fine. Could you add the filling and sort calling part? Along with the execution output if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your sort is that `orderNum` must be constantly evaluated within the inner while loop. But you're only evaluating it once per outer loop cycle. So best to remove that assignment and place the `compareTo` within the while loop condition. You can see this in the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("boy", "Eat", "apple", "code", "Tea"));
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int j = i;
    while (j > 0 && list.get(j).toLowerCase()
            .compareTo(list.get(j - 1).toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        String temp = list.get(j);
        list.set(j, list.get(j - 1));
        list.set(j - 1, temp);
        j--;
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[apple, boy, code, Eat, Tea]
```

To make the `while statement` a little less cluttered you can use the predefined case insensitive comparator and pass the `list` and `index` to the lambda.  It returns a `boolean` as a result of the comparison.

```
BiFunction<List<String>, Integer, Boolean> comp = (lst, idx)->
       String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(list.get(idx), 
                                 list.get(idx-1))<0;
```

Then use it like this.

```
while (j > 0 && comp.apply(list,j)) {
```